# TAPI on Windows 2008 64 bit edition

Tags: vb6, 64-bit, windows-server-2008, tapi

I have an old app I support (written in VB6) and it interfaces with TAPI.  Recently the app got installed on the Windows 2008 Server 64-bit edition.  However, the TSP driver for TAPI installation, even though, it got installed, gave an innocuous looking warning.

However, the driver (which is 32-bit for sure), does not appear to have been recognized by Windows 2008.  I tried hitting the 32-bit version of the Control Panel, but it was not there either.

So the question is this: does TAPI on 64-bit systems require a 64-bit driver?  If that is the case, will my 32-bit application be able to work with the 64-bit TAPI driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first answer is horribly wrong. TAPI is a windows API and is supported in every modern version of windows! Of course it is natively supported. The issue is purely a 32bit/64bit issue. A 32 bit process can not call into a 64bit process or visa versa. In order to run a TAPI application, you must have the correct TSP. A 32bit application will need a 32 bit TSP. If you have a 64bit compiled application, you will need a 64bit TSP, or perhaps a 32bit TSP that extracts its UI functions into a separate dll.

Answer (score 2):

TAPI is not nativly supported in 64Bit Windows though there are ways to get around this. You can run a Virtual PC 32Bit session on the machine and use it's TAPI support or you can try one of the 3rd Party TAPI drivers outr there.

This one will work with both 32Bit and 64Bit systems:

[TAPI DRIVER](http://wareseeker.com/download/demo-tapi-driver-3.1.rar/240160)